# Number of non-isomorphic block graphs on n nodes

Tags: graph-theory, isomorphism-testing

A block in a graph is a maximal connected subgraph that has no cut-vertex. A complete graph having $n$ nodes is denoted by $K_n$. A block graph is a graph in which each block is a complete graph. For example in figure a block graph with blocks $K_2,K_2,K_3,K_4 $ and $K_5$. What is the number of non-isomorphic block graphs on $n$ nodes?.  [image]

Comment: You mean, "What is the number of non-isomorphic block graphs on $n$ nodes?", right?

Comment: Now I have edited it.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be http://oeis.org/A035053 .  References and formulae are there.